# Why is this funciton not loading right first in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, bots

I'm writing a twitter bot in Node.JS but I have a function that is using an npm library called "scrapejs" it grabs the data from yahoo finance and works just fine, problem is though I have the function loading after the code from the botton runs first and not a clue as to why. I had my tweeting section of the bot working before but if Im grabbing data from the web scrape I can't have that running after tweeting.

Here's the code:

```
console.log("The Bot Is Starting To Work.");

var sp = require('scrapejs').init({
    cc: 2, // up to 2 concurrent requests
    delay: 5 * 1 // delay .05 seconds before each request
});

sp.load('https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=CADUSD=X')
    .then(function ($, res) {
        //$.q("//h3[@class='r']/a").forEach(function(node){ //Adding the HTML Tags to filter the data
        console.log("Scraping The Web...");
        $.q("//span[@class='time_rtq_ticker']/span").forEach(function (node) {
            var res = {
                title: node.textContent //Always returns { title: 'NUMBER'} (When Working)
            }
            console.log(res);
            return res;
        })
    })
    .fail(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    })


console.log("Why does this part load first??"); // This part comes first before the function above
```

Heres what the output looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVpTo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

node.js works asynchronously, this means that the rows in your code **starts** one after the other, and each of them ends when it ends - the third row **will not wait** for the second one to finish before starting.

Since your second function is heavy, it takes some time to run, much more than a simple `console.log()`, there for the last row will end first

Comment: I got it working in order now with a setTimeout function for now and I'll work on a better solution after I sort out all the other work. Thanks!

Comment: @CorgJR - usually when you want something to happen after some other function, you put it in the function's callback. The problem with timeout is that you are using some arbitrary time there - in some cases you will wait too long, on others the time might not be enough

Answer (score -2):

For making your life easier you can use `deasync` module.

https://github.com/abbr/deasync

- Just install it using: `npm i -s deasync`

Then you can convert any async function to sync one.